# How to write a conference title correctly

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, word-order

I am creating name tags (badges) for an international science conference. There will be discussions of science and technical questions. I don't understand how to properly write titles. If I translate literally from my native language, it would be

> Scientific-technical conference.

But I feel it is wrong.

**Question:** How is the title of a conference written correctly?

Comment: Science & Technology Conference. Rather than technical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context, it's hard to be sure, but it would likely be a "Science and Technology Conference" or a "Conference of Science and Technology"

Comment: Thanks. A year later we will prepare new conference